# OSGI, OSGI - bundle and Hazelcast deserialization class not found exception

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, hazelcast, osgi-bundle

My Question is

I have two osgi bundles, In which one bundle has hazelcast (3.3 version) jar and I have exported all the packages in it... which means the other bundle can use all the packages of hazelcast available in first bundle.

So what I planned is, 
    -> One bundle is for keeping the hazelcast jar as common bundle.
    -> Other bundle is for performing the business operations in which the first bundle will be the dependent bundle for this,

I have the hazelcast xml which has a serialization factory mapping in it.

Note : The serialization factory class is there in other bundle (Not in hazelcast jar bundle), So what happens is when I start the hazelcast server, It clearly says that the serialization factory class is not found.

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.beans.SerializableFactory
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceBuilder.buildDataSerializableFactories(SerializationServiceBuilder.java:290)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceBuilder.addConfigDataSerializableFactories(SerializationServiceBuilder.java:247)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceBuilder.build(SerializationServiceBuilder.java:169)
at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.createSerializationService(Node.java:193)
at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:120)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:153)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:136)
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:112)
at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
```

For your INFORMATION, I already tried **config.setClassloader**

Comment: Can you provide the content of your hazelcast.xml and the code snippet you use to pull up hazelcast?

Comment: Christian, It is very clear, There is no problem with xml configuration, Its an OSGI problem, Anywaz, I will add it                         <serialization>
     <data-serializable-factories>
        <data-serializable-factory
   factory-id="1">com.test.beans.SerializableFactory
        </data-serializable-factory>
     </data-serializable-factories>
  </serialization>

Comment: Christian, It just refers to the factory class,

Comment: I suspect you set config::setClassLoader to the bundle classloader of the bundle that contains the factory class?

Comment: Sure it is an OSGi related problem but without the exact code you use to instantiate Hazelcast we will have no clue what is going on.